# Python Raspberry Pi Create bars in Kivy

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, sensors, gpio

My code does not work as expected.
The bars should be created only when read_SensorGeral is true, the buzzer should be activated only when read_SensorGeral is true and read_Sensor is false.
As create other bars only barGeral equals True ?
My code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #pino sensor 1
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)     #pino sensor 2
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)     #pino sensor 3
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)  #pino sensor 4
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #pino sensor 5
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #pino sensor 6
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #pino sensor 7
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)   #pino sensor 8
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)      #pino sensor 9
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #pino master
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) #pino buzzer


pin_Master = 19
pin_1 = 26
pin_2 = 20
pin_3 = 21
pin_4 = 4
pin_5 = 17
pin_6 = 27
pin_7 = 22
pin_8 = 10
pin_9 = 9


class MainLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass 

class bar(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1)
    g = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, pin, p1, p2, **kwargs):
        super(bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pin = pin
        self.p1  = p1
        self.p2  = p2
        self.pin_Buzzer = 12
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.canvas.clear()
        if  self.read_SensorGeral(self.pin) == True:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.g, 1, 0, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(self.p1,self.p2), size=(35,300))
            GPIO.output(12, 0)
        else:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.r, 0, 0, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(self.p1,self.p2), size=(35,30))
            GPIO.output(12, 1)
    def read_Sensor(self, pin):
        sensor = GPIO.wait_for_edge(pin, GPIO.BOTH, timeout=200)                                                                   
        if sensor is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def read_SensorGeral(self, pin):
        sensor = GPIO.wait_for_edge(pin, GPIO.BOTH, timeout=200)                                                                   
        if sensor is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    class MainApp(App):
        def build(self):
            Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
            self.mainlayout = Widget()
            barGeral = bar(pin_Master, 26, 100)
            bar1 = bar(pin_1, 26, 30)
            bar2 = bar(pin_2, 106, 30)
            bar3 = bar(pin_3, 186, 30)
            bar4 = bar(pin_4, 266, 30)
            bar5 = bar(pin_5, 346, 30)
            bar6 = bar(pin_6, 426, 30)
            bar7 = bar(pin_7, 506, 30)
            bar8 = bar(pin_8, 586, 30)
            bar9 = bar(pin_9, 666, 30)

            self.mainlayout.add_widget(barGeral)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar1)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar2)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar3)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar4)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar5)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar6)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar7)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar8)
            self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar9)
            return self.mainlayout
    try:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            MainApp().run()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Programa finalizado!")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your update like this, to get your conditions right:

```
def update(self, dt):
    self.canvas.clear()
    if  self.read_SensorGeral(self.pin) == True:
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.g, 1, 0, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(self.p1,self.p2), size=(35,300))
        if not self.read_Sensor(self.pin):
            GPIO.output(12, 1)
    else:
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.r, 0, 0, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(self.p1,self.p2), size=(35,30))
        GPIO.output(12, 0)
```

There might be another problem tou. You run `update()` 60 times per second, but you allow a pin timeout of 200. That means you have several `update()` threads running at the same time. That might give unexpected results.
Maybe you should make the update as a loop in one thread per bar. Like so:

```
from thread import start_new_thread



class bar(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1)
    g = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, pin, p1, p2, **kwargs):
        super(bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pin = pin
        self.p1  = p1
        self.p2  = p2
        self.pin_Buzzer = 12

        start_new_thread(self.update())


    def update(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        if  self.read_SensorGeral(self.pin) == True:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.g, 1, 0, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(self.p1,self.p2), size=(35,300))
            if not self.read_Sensor(self.pin):
                GPIO.output(12, 1)
        else:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.r, 0, 0, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(self.p1,self.p2), size=(35,30))
            GPIO.output(12, 0)

        time.sleep(10) # maybe a little time sleep between the updates
        self.update()
```

And initiate the update loop in your `__init__` method. `self.update()`

Comment: @VictorSued did you remove the clock? And are you the pins are shifting, since you wait for edges?

Comment: commented the clock, remove timeout in wait edge and edited def uptade () equals you posted, iam run not write bars.... white screen....

Comment: @VictorSued I can ofcourse only take your word for, that you really get an edge on the pin. I cannot test that.

Comment: @VictorSued also you need to run self.update() in init once, to start it. And make it run it self in update. I will update the answer

Comment: @VictorSued sry :) I see a problem here. I will update my answer. There will need to be one thread for each bar

Comment: preserv timeout in wait for edge ? or remove ?

Comment: @VictorSued no sry, preserve. Maybe you want it to turn off the buzzer, if no edge right?

Comment: 1 - While pin Pulse... up the bar green
2 - If pin not Pulse ... down the bar..
3 - While bar down on the buzzer...

I need work in realtime.. this code very delay for update bars...

Comment: @VictorSued yea then you need a timeout. But you cannot be sure that the pulse edge will hit in those 200 ms. Shouldnt you look if the pin is high or low instead?

Comment: everytime pin high and low... is an sensor infrared.. i need detected sensor stop pulse or return pulse...
If sensor pulse everytime... bar gree up OK or not Bar red down and buzzer ON.